# Excel to pdf, bad image quality?

Tags: c#, excel

OK, I have Excel(from Excel 2010 Workbook Template) sheet with picture on it and when I export this sheet to pdf i get very bad image quality. Text is fine, but image not at all.

I use this code to export excel to pdf:

```
xlSS.ExportAsFixedFormat(
    XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, 
    path, 
    XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard);
```

Is there better way to save(export) .xlsx/.xls to .pdf so I could get nice image quality?

Here is comparation, the first one is when extracted to pdf:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you export the PDF manually in Excel (by going to `Save As => PDF`) and select `Optimize for Standard` is the quality better?

Comment: I just checked and the quality is the same(not good). It has this blur shadows all over itself(and that is what is bothering me). Interesting thing is that image has nice quality when image is on sheet.

Comment: Ok, that means that this is not a coding issue, it's just an `Excel => PDF` issue, does it look as bad if you export to XPS?

Comment: It looks the same when exported to xps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Solution is that you have to resize picture after its insert in sheet, otherwise it looses quality.

I've done it like that and maintained image quality even when exporting sheet into pdf file.