# I'm making an excel pdf with python, but the quality of the image in excel deteriorates

Tags: python, excel, pdf, converters

Quality in images deteriorates when converting excel to pdf
my code is like this:

everything is fine but the pictures are blurry

```
enter code here

import os
import comtypes.client

SOURCE_DIR = r'C:\Users\ADEM\Desktop'
TARGET_DIR = r'C:\Users\ADEM\Desktop'

app = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Excel.Application')
app.Visible = False

infile = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(SOURCE_DIR), 'eessa.xlsx')
outfile = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(TARGET_DIR), 'essa51.pdf')

doc = app.Workbooks.Open(infile)
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, outfile, 1, 0)
doc.Close()

app.Quit()`
```

Comment: the picture is better but this time the texts are intertwined

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?
[Excel to pdf, bad image quality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637948/excel-to-pdf-bad-image-quality)

> You have to resize picture after inserting in sheet, otherwise it looses quality. This shall maintain the image quality.

Comment: I resized it but the result did not change, what kind of resizing are you talking about?

Comment: I am not sure since this is not my answer, but similar question answered previously. You can try and change about some attributes related to images of the file to be saved as pdf, if the library allows it